# How can I disable the (respective) vote buttons once a user has voted?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm currently trying to add a voting system to the comment section on my website. So far, I have created 2 database table called `comments` and `votes`. The `comments` table contains a column where the score of each comment is stored. The `votes` table stores all the information about each individual vote made on a comment - including the unique user ID of whoever made the vote, the unique comment ID of the comment being voted on, and whether it's an upvote or a downvote.

So far, I have created a function which updates the score of the comment, and a function which adds the unique vote data into the `votes` table.

However, I'm still trying to work out how to piece these together to create a `userCanVote()` function which checks whether a user can vote, and disables the respective voting button if they have already used it.

How should I go about creating this `userCanVote()` function to disable the correct button?

Comment: Well you obviously start by checking the database for whether a record for the combination user id and comment id already exists …

Comment: maybe SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vote WHERE user_id = 'logged_in_user_id' AND title = 'current_title'. then if count > 0, return true

Comment: @ChrysUgwu That method would not allow the user to alter their vote once it has been placed.

Comment: @JohnSmith well then u can add an else statement or return false. if false that means the user have voted b4 then u can come up with the logic of updating their vote

Answer (score 1):

many method you can use
you can use ip and stored in database if the ip exist the button don't appear
you can also use if the user is login the session and store his username or id in a column if this column have this id don't show the button